# a-frame VR Rotate Box When Clicked

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create a web page that contains an A-Frame box that rotates 90 degrees when it's clicked.  I've tried various things including using the aframe-event-set-component library.  I can't quite seem to get it to work.  I suspect I have a syntax problem but I cannot figure out my mistake.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my code using the aframe-event-set-component.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tim

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cursor</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Changing properties in response to cursor component events"></meta>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngokevin/kframe/master/components/event-set/examples/basic/preview.gif"></meta>
<script src="node_modules\aframe-event-set-component\examples\build.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #FCB241"
            event-set__1="_event: click; material.color:red 
     attribute="rotation dur='5000' repeat='0' to='0 90 0'""
            event-set__2="_event: mouseenter; material.color: #5A67A6"
            event-set__3="_event: mouseleave; material.color: #FCB241"
            position="-1 0 -2">
      </a-entity>

      <a-sky color="#D68D08"></a-sky>

     <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-entity cursor
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 
 0.016"
              material="color: #EEE"
              position="0 0 -1"></a-entity>
     </a-entity>
   </a-scene>

    <!--githubcorner-->
    <a href="https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/event-set/examples/basic/" class="github-corner">
     <svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="fill: #111; color: #EFEFEF; position: fixed; bottom: 0; border: 0; left: 0; transform: rotate(180deg); opacity: 0.8">
       <path d="M0,0 L115,115 L130,115 L142,142 L250,250 L250,0 Z"></path><path d="M128.3,109.0 C113.8,99.7 119.0,89.6 119.0,89.6 C122.0,82.7 120.5,78.6 120.5,78.6 C119.2,72.0 123.4,76.3 123.4,76.3 C127.3,80.9 125.5,87.3 125.5,87.3 C122.9,97.6 130.6,101.9 134.4,103.2" fill="currentColor" style="transform-origin: 130px 106px;" class="octo-arm"></path><path d="M115.0,115.0 C114.9,115.1 118.7,116.5 119.8,115.4 L133.7,101.6 C136.9,99.2 139.9,98.4 142.2,98.6 C133.8,88.0 127.5,74.4 143.8,58.0 C148.5,53.4 154.0,51.2 159.7,51.0 C160.3,49.4 163.2,43.6 171.4,40.1 C171.4,40.1 176.1,42.5 178.8,56.2 C183.1,58.6 187.2,61.8 190.9,65.4 C194.5,69.0 197.7,73.2 200.1,77.6 C213.8,80.2 216.3,84.9 216.3,84.9 C212.7,93.1 206.9,96.0 205.4,96.6 C205.1,102.4 203.0,107.8 198.3,112.5 C181.9,128.9 168.3,122.5 157.7,114.1 C157.9,116.9 156.7,120.9 152.7,124.9 L141.0,136.5 C139.8,137.7 141.6,141.9 141.8,141.8 Z" fill="currentColor" class="octo-body"></path>
      </svg>
   </a>
   <style>.github-corner:hover .octo-arm{animation:octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out}@keyframes octocat-wave{0%,100%{transform:rotate(0)}20%,60%{transform:rotate(-25deg)}40%,80%{transform:rotate(10deg)}}@media (max-width:500px){.github-corner:hover .octo-arm{animation:none}.github-corner .octo-arm{animation:octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out}}
    </style>
    <!--endgithubcorner-->
 </body>
 </html>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Timothy,

If You wanna just rotate it, add the rotation attribute to the event:

```
event-set__1="_event: click; material.color:#ff0000;rotation:0 90 0"
```

On the other hand, i presume you want to have an animation, so You will have to either:
use the `<a-animation>` component, or use kevin's ngo animation-component: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation
You'd need to declare an animation to 0 90 0, make a startEvent, and make the click emit that event:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #FCB241"
            event-set__1="_event: click; material.color:#ff0000;"

            event-set__2="_event: mouseenter; material.color: #0000ff"
            event-set__3="_event: mouseleave; material.color: #FCB241"
            position="-1 0 -2"
            animation__rotate="property: rotation; dir: forward; dur: 1000;
                                 easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 0 90 0;
                                 startEvents:click">

      </a-entity>
```

The following plunk shows how to make it rotate on click with the animation component:

https://plnkr.co/edit/k9Jc5qEG0ckEovquEZi4?p=preview

If You don't want the animation, just replace Your event-set__1 with mine.

PERSONALLY i'd rather register my own component @ AFRAME.registerComponent (name, definition), because I like to handle events by on own.